# Question about a technical detail on the definition of continuity at the end points of a domain.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I've been tasked with proving that $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$, and the approach that I've decided to take to do so is to define a new function $\tilde{f}:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ as follows
$$
\tilde{f}(x)=\begin{cases}f(x) & x\in(0,1] \\0 & x=0\end{cases}
$$
Then, since $[0,1]$ is a compact interval, if $\tilde{f}(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, it is also uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ (and so by extension, $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$). I just have a couple of questions about continuity at the left end point of $[0,1]$, $x=0$. To prove that $\tilde{f}(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, I wish to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\tilde{f}(x)=\tilde{f}(0)=0
$$
However, since, strictly speaking, $\tilde{f}(x)$ is not defined outside of $[0,1]$, would it be sufficient to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\tilde{f}(x)=\tilde{f}(0)=0
$$
and hence conclude from this fact that $\tilde{f}(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$? If it is sufficient, can I then apply the sandwich theorem as follows
$$
-x\leq x\sin(1/x)\leq x \\
\lim_{x\to0^+}-x\leq\lim_{x\to0^+}x\sin(1/x)\leq\lim_{x\to0^+}x \\
0\leq\lim_{x\to0^+}x\sin(1/x)\leq0 \\
\implies\lim_{x\to0^+}x\sin(1/x)=0
$$
And hence $\tilde{f}(x)\to0=\tilde{f}(0)$ as $x\to0^+$, as required for $\tilde{f}(x)$ to be continuous at $x=0$?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your approach is correct. It's typically assumed that continuity at end points is only from one side. It may be continuous from both sides, but it's not what's of interest.

Comment: You can just consider $(0,1]$ as a subspace of $X=[0,1]$, with the subspace toplogy of $\mathbb R$. Then, $[0,\delta)$ is an open set in $X$ on which you can apply the definition of continuity.